# Looping a function through a list of dataframes is very slow

Tags: r, performance, unique, purrr, furrr

I have a list, which contains 4438 dataframes with different sizes. I am not sure how to make a reproducible example, but the way I obtained the list is using the expand.grid function to have a dataframe with all the possible combination of elements:

```
citation <- citation %>% 
    map_depth(., 1, expand.grid)
```

List before applying expand.grid
[image]

List after applying expand.grid
[image]

What I am going to achieve is for each dataframe, counting the number of unique values per row, and finding the minimum number of unique values in the dataframe.

First, I write the function below

```
fun1 <- function(res){ 
    min(apply(res,1,function(x) length(unique(x)))) 
}
```

Then, apply the function to each dataframe:

```
library(furrr)
plan(multisession, workers = 4)
min_set <- c()
min_set <- citation %>% future_map_dbl(fun1)
```

However, the calculation is super slow, almost 30 mins to complete. I would like to find another way to accelerate the performance. Looking forward to hear the solution from you guys. Thank you in advance

Comment: `as.vector(mode ='list', length = 4448)` to preallocate rather than `c(` should help.

Comment: @Chris I don't see how preallocation would help here. Preallocation works best when you are trying to avoid growing a vector one element at a time in a loop. Function like `map_dbl` don't have that problem. I think the bigger problem is using `apply()` on a data.frame because it has to convert to a matrix before performing the operation.

Comment: Point taken, thanks.

Comment: Yes I also think `apply` is the culprit. But I am not sure how I can improve it

Comment: I generally don't interact with questions that do not include a reproducible example that can be used for testing. You might try changing the order of columns to expand.grid to reshape the data. R stores data.frames by column so row-wise operations tend to be inefficient.

Comment: @MrFlick I have added the reprex, which is the subset from 15 first dataframes of citation list. Please let me know if you can work on that

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 2):

To speed up the current approach of enumerating the combinations, use `rowTabulate` from the `Rfast` package (or `rowTabulates` from the `matrixStats` package).

However, it will be much faster to get the desired results with the `setcover` function in the `adagio` package, which solves the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) directly (i.e., without the use of `expand.grid`) via integer linear programming with `lp` from the `lpSolve` package.

```
library(Rfast) # for the rowTabulate function
library(adagio) # for the setcover function

# reproducible example data
set.seed(1141593349)
citation1 <- list(
  lapply(c(5,2,8,12,6,38), function(size) sample(50, size)),
  lapply(c(5,2,8,12,7), function(size) sample(50, size))
)
# get all combinations of the indices of the unique values for each list in citation1
citation2 <- lapply(citation1, function(x) expand.grid(lapply(x, match, table = unique(unlist(x)))))

# original solution
fun1 <- function(res) min(apply(res, 1, function(x) length(unique(x))))
# faster version of the original solution
fun2 <- function(res) min(rowsums(rowTabulate(as.matrix(res)) > 0L))
# linear programming solution (uses citation1 rather than citation2)
fun3 <- function(res) {
  v <- unlist(res)
  m <- matrix(0L, max(v), length(res))
  m[cbind(v, rep.int(seq_along(res), lengths(res)))] <- 1L
  setcover(m)$objective
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fun1 = sapply(citation2, fun1),
                               fun2 = as.integer(sapply(citation2, fun2)),
                               fun3 = as.integer(sapply(citation1, fun3)),
                               times = 10,
                               check = "identical")
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr       min          lq        mean      median          uq         max
#>  fun1 1110.4976 1162.003601 1217.049501 1204.608151 1281.121601 1331.057001
#>  fun2  101.5173  113.123501  142.265371  145.964502  165.788700  187.196301
#>  fun3    1.4038    1.461101    1.734781    1.850701    1.870801    1.888702
```

Comment: I was unable to upvote but I tried and it helps a lot. Thank you so much